# React component's local state not getting updated with onChildClick

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-component, react-state, google-map-react

I'm trying to update the react component's local state when an element is clicked

```
onChildClick={this.onChildClickCallback}
```

where `onChildClickCallback` is a helper function outside the render which is as follows:

```
onChildClickCallback = key => {
            this.setState({ items: this.props.data, newKey: key }, function() {
                console.log(this.state);
            });
        };
```

I've written the above console.log in callback as I've read somewhere state might not get updated immediately.

But, whatever the value I pass to the state, it is not getting updated and console is logging the same old value of key and items.
What am I missing here?

UPDATED CODE:

```
render() {
        console.log(this.state);
        const items = this.props.data;

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <GoogleMap
                    center={this.state.center}
                    onChildClick={this.onChildClickCallback}
                >
                    {items.map(item => (
                        <Marker
                            key={item.id}
                            lat={item.lattitude}
                            lng={item.longitude}
                            place={place}
                        />
                    ))}
                </GoogleMap>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
```

And you have onChildClickCallback already. I wanted to update the state and rerender the component when onChildClickCallback is triggered.

Comment: I dont think there is enough of your code here to pinpoint what's wrong. But, I would imagine the issue is with how you're using onChildClickCallBack in your child compomnent.

Comment: As was mentioned above, can you please add the component(parent/child)  snippets as well

Comment: Why would you set the `items` key in your state to the same data that is in `this.props.data`... that is generally an anti-pattern in React without a very good reason.

Comment: @jered can you please elaborate. I was trying to update the props and set that to local state. May I know what's wrong with that and what's the alternative approach?

Comment: if at all we cannot update the props in a component, I could see the updated props when logged in console, the why not add it to the state ?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo and Bryan please find the code updated

Comment: I deleted my answer since I was looking wrong lib. I guess thats the correct one [google-map-react](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react). Anyway, the next step on debugging that would be to test that `onChildClick` gets called at all. Ie. maybe add some `console.log`  on top before `setState`. State changes are delayed by frame or two some times, not more than that. Also, you might want to convert that one regular `function` in `onChildClick` to arrow function just to make sure it has correctly bound `this`.